Noise coming from Driver front tire at low speeds
I have a 2018 Odyssey. For several months now, it has been making a consistent "bumping sound" at low speeds. I just heard it about every 20-30 seconds while driving under 30 mph around my neighborhood. It sounds like road noise, similar to when there are small bumps in the road, and I can feel it ever so slightly. My main concern is whether or not this is a safety issue?
The car was just state-inspected by Honda and it passed. I asked Honda about the noise, and they said they want $200 just to diagnose it. However, isn't something like wheel bearings supposed to be covered by the safety inspection? If my wheel seized up, Honda might be liable.
I jacked up the car.  Attached is what I saw.  I put the vehicle in neutral.  This is an electronic transmission.  It would set itself back in park after I spun the wheel.  There was drag on the wheel, but I think that might be the cars electronics screwing around with the "free spin" test?
Do you have any suggestions to rule out safety issues on my own?









You can always jack both sides up, keeping the tires on, and rotate the wheels yourself (no engine/transmission needed). This might tell you what you want to know. I really don't think it would, though. If you're going 30mph, the wheels are spinning at a pretty good clip. If there was a problem with a wheel bearing, you'd most likely feel it before you heard it, and then it would be a constant low pitched hum.
